# Limit as epsilon approaches 0

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Could anyone shed some lights on this problem:

what's the limit of $y(x,a,\varepsilon)$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$

$$\def\pow#1{e^{#1/\varepsilon^2}}
y(x,a,\varepsilon) = \frac{\pow{-ax}\left(\pow{wx}-\pow{-wx}\right)}{\pow{-a}\left(\pow{w}-\pow{-w}\right)}\\w=\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon^2}$$

[(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paNnk.gif)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly find the solution attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$y(x,a,\epsilon) = \frac{e^{-ax/\epsilon^2}\sinh\left(\frac{wx}{\epsilon^2}\right)}{e^{-a/\epsilon^2}\sinh\left(\frac{w}{\epsilon^2}\right)}$$

Comment: Dear Ivo, thanks for your comment. The official answer is: 
$$y(x,a,\epsilon) = \frac{e^{-x/2a}-e^{-2ax/\epsilon^2}}{e^{-1/2a}-e^{-2a/\epsilon^2}}$$       I tried to use L'hospital but didn't work.